# How to merge each 5 lines into 1 line from 1100 lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file containing 1100 lines, I want to merge each 5 lines into one line for all 1100 lines.

I can do it manually, but it really takes time.

I used replace function with expression:

Find: `\r\n` replace with `(space)`

But it requires one by one replacement

Can anyone help?

---

My file looks like:

```
john 
micheal
johnson
mike
alberto
lorenzo
sebstian ................ till 1100 lines
```

I want to make every 5 lines together in one line for all 1100, so it should look like:

```
john micheal johnson mike alberto 
lorenzo sebstian ...... till 5
and so on
```

---

Pics to explain more:

It's currently like this:

[image]

I want it to be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the line separator is `\r\n`.

Make sure you set `Search Mode` to `Regular Expression` and `. matches new-line` is **unchecked**.

Find:

```
(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n
```

Replace with:

```
\1 \2 \3 \4 \5\r\n
```

**Explanation:**

`.` - any character.
`*` - zero or more of what's before it.
So `.*` - zero or more of any character.
`\r\n` - new-line.
`(...)` (in brackets) - assigns what's matched the next group number, starting from 1 (so the first thing in brackets is group 1, second is group 2, third is group 3, etc.)
`\1` - references the first group (similarly for `\2`-`\5`).

See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for more information.